# Difference between elemMatch with and without "$" flag

Tags: mongoose

Writing $elemMatch or elemMatch, what is the difference with and without "$"? What is this "$" flag doing actually here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just how mongodb [operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/) are defined. So you have to call them as such. see link for more details. If you use without `$` you wouldn't be referencing a default mongodb function. I wouldn't worry too much about the `$` unless working with the [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) where you'll need to understand how it actually works.